# Alternatives to getContentResolver().query()

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am looking for alternatives to getContentResolver().query() which will not require Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no means of querying a `ContentProvider` except via `ContentResolver`, which needs a `Context`.